# Including a file in json_encode()

Tags: php, jquery

Thsi does not seem to work:

```
$msg="Your changes have been saved successfully";

$view=include('application/view/admin/cms/_slides-current.php');

$return_array=array('success'=>true, 'msg'=>$msg, 'view'=>$view);

echo json_encode($return_array);
```

The array needs to be passed back to a jQuery ajax success callback. Anybody know how it should be done?

The include file is simply a HTML template. This HTML template will be inserted on to the page.

Is there any way other than using json_encode() to do what I am trying to do?

```
success: function(result){
    alert(result.msg);

    if(result.success == true)
    {
        $('#slides').html(result.view);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your include file look like. Does it even return something?

Comment: Does the include return anything???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is a statement and not a function (disregard the function.include.php part). It will not return the parsed result to your `$view` variabe, although the file will be included just above your `json_encode`.

You should use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture the evaluated result of the view in the manner described by mihneasime:

```
ob_start();
include 'application/view/admin/cms/_slides-current.php';
$view = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: @PeeHaa - I believe you are referring to [this section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-129) which states that includes may return the value of a `return()` in the included file.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. I've also seen a very similar solution to yours in a framework that I use regularly - the only major difference is that their version has `ob_implicit_flush(false);` right after `ob_start` - does this make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

```
ob_start();
include 'application/view/admin/cms/_slides-current.php';
$view = ob_get_clean();
```

Should do the trick as joar suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fopen`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and friends to read files. `include` is for *including* them.